# How can I give this grid expandable rows? -Ext JS

Tags: extjs, grid

I have tried just about everything to give this grid expandable rows. Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.metadata.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.metadatalist',
    title: '<center>Results</center>',
    store: 'Metadata', 
    requires: ['Ext.*'],    
    collapsible: true,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [
            { xtype: 'tbtext',  text: 'Loading...', itemId: 'recordNumberItem'  },
            '->',
            { text: 'Print', itemId: 'print' },
            '-',
            { text: 'Export', itemId: 'export' }
        ]
    }],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Technical Name',  dataIndex: 'TECH_NAME', flex: 4, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'KBE ID', dataIndex: 'KBE_ID', flex: 2, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'KBE Name', dataIndex: 'KBE_NAME', flex: 3, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'View Name', dataIndex: 'VIEW_NAME', flex: 4, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'Database/Schema', dataIndex: 'DB_SCHEMA', flex: 3, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'Privacy', dataIndex: 'PRIVACY_INDICATOR', flex: 3, tdCls: 'grid_cell'}
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments); //Calls the parent method of the current method in order to override 


    }
});
```

And here's where I instantiate it in my app.js

```
{ xtype: 'metadatalist', padding: '5px 5px 5px 5px', height: 430, width: '100%', hidden: true}
```

I have tried the rowexpander plugin, but I'm not sure if I put it in the right place. If anyone sees a red flag or can help me out with how to implement this rowexpander, I would greatly appreciate it. I've posted several times about this, and so far have received little to no help. I'm using Ext JS 4.1.1

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the rowexpander plugin in the grid configuration and you need to create an XTemplate for the information presented when the row is expanded.  Did you try and follow this example?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid/grid-plugins.html

Comment: It gives me  'TypeError: name is undefined', and I have tried it many times

Comment: Everything works great until i try to put in a rowexpander. Am I missing a Ext.requires somewhere?

Comment: So do you get the data to load in the grid without using the row expander?

Comment: Yes perfectly, it's literally trying to call 'ptype: 'rowexpander' that breaks the app

Comment: Can you show the full code with the plugin definition and xtemplate?  Also please show the code for the model as well.

Comment: So I got it to work, but instead of any kind of meaningful data, all I get is [object Object] in my expanded row

Comment: Need to see the model and the json data you are returning

Comment: I wasn't using json data yet

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I needed to set my Loader path so that it could find RowExpander.js. Here's what I did:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'extjs/examples/ux'); // change this for your environment

Ext.require([ 'Ext.ux.RowExpander' ]);
```